# Web Control Library in VS Professional 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2013 with Update 4, but I can't find the Web Control Library under Visual C# templates. I also tried to look for it in the online template but couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: [From this VS 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164708%28v=vs.120%29.aspx), if you click the template link in the first paragraph you will be taken to ASP.NET Server Control Template (if you change the version to 2005, you'll see the template link to Web Control Library). I presume Microsoft has changed the name